# NSSlider event not firing

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsslider

I have got an event on my NSSlider with this code:

```
- (IBAction)optOndoorzichtigheidChange:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *opacity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[optOndoorzichtigheidSlider value]];
    [defaults setObject:opacity forKey:@"opacity"];
    [mainWindow setAlphaValue:[optOndoorzichtigheidSlider doubleValue]];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [optOndoorzichtigheidLabel setStringValue:opacity];
    NSLog(@"fired");
}
```

But it's not firing and the console gives this message: 2011-01-09 19:31:18.994 Nistract[1337:a0f] -[NSSlider value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100427400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use this code and it seems to work:

```
- (IBAction)optOndoorzichtigheidChange:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *opacity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[optOndoorzichtigheidSlider intValue]];
    [defaults setObject:opacity forKey:@"opacity"];
    [[mainWindow animator] setAlphaValue:((double) [optOndoorzichtigheidSlider intValue] / 100)];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [optOndoorzichtigheidLabel setStringValue:opacity];
    NSLog(@"fired");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The method *is* executing.  You're just crashing because you're trying to execute a method that doesn't exist.

The problem is this line:

```
NSString *opacity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[optOndoorzichtigheidSlider value]];
```

`NSSlider` does not have a `value` method.  It has a `doubleValue` method that returns a `double`.

Comment: Thanks, that was also a problem, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've hard-coded your slider. Instead of calls like this

```
[optOndoorzichtigheidSlider intValue];
```

try using the `sender`

```
[sender intValue];
```

And it looks like you are updating a label with the value here

```
[optOndoorzichtigheidLabel setStringValue:opacity];
```

When you could consider using Bindings instead.